# Is there a way to password encrypt a compressed archive in powershell without using 3rd party tools?

Tags: powershell, compression, password-protection, password-encryption

After using a powershell command to compress a folder:

```
powershell -Command "& {Compress-Archive -Update -Path 'C:\myfolder' -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath C:\myfolder.zip}"
```

is there another powershell command to password protect/encrypt the resulting myfolder.zip archived file?

Comment: @iRon he's asking of Encryption, not Extraction.  As for the question, neither dotnet framework, nor Windows Shell support encrypted archives. So probably not.

Comment: I've found many examples of people asking similar questions on various sites, and zero answers which do not involve 3rd party utilities such as 7zip.  I think the answer might be that you need a 3rd party utility.

Comment: You are correct, the answer is 'no.'

Answer (score 4):

As of July 2020, `Compress-Archive` and the command-line tool `tar` do not provide encryption options. A 3rd-party app is required.